# How to make Json Response payload without html <p> tags

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have php script like this

```
$resultx = array("Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800");print json_encode($resultx,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

and i want to get the resultx data using this ajax

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "[[~12]]",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data:{type:"dtpengajuan"},
    });
```

result :

```
<p>["Tiger Nixon","System Architect","Edinburgh",5421,"2011\/04\/25","$320,800"]</p>
```

my question, why the response payload always have `<p>` tags

i am using PHP 5.6.38-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Sep 20 2018 02:32:02)

Comment: Where do you see this result?

Comment: I tried your code and I don't get the <p> tage.
Maybe you can try adding `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` before the print statement

Comment: @u_mulder, i see using inspect element at response payload tab

Comment: @motia, already try that and still get <p> tags.

Answer (score 0):

already find the solution, not ideal but at least i can continue my project.

i had to save the array at txt file, and call it using ajax to my datatable, so i can avoid the `<p>` tags

if anybody have better solution I am very happy to give it a try